# AWS API Gateway Mutual TLS certificate selection notification not shown in browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, mutual-authentication

How can I get an URL exposed through AWS API Gateway to trigger the notification popup for certificate selection in the browser?

I have an API Gateway that (I hope) has been correctly configure to use mutual TLS authentication. For example, unless I provide the client certificate, a curl request fails. But, when I try to open an URL directly in Firefox, I only get a blocked request in the developer tools' console, rather a popup asking me to select a certificate to use.

Comment: As a workaround, use incognito mode (assuming firefox has an equivalent), you should then get a popup.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that Firefox does not offer the option to import a certificate if there are none already imported. But, after importing it and reloading the URL, it gives the option to select the client certificate I want to use.